# Links in post content don't work on home page

Tags: permalinks

Some of my posts have links inside the post content. When I click on the post, the link in the content is underlined and clickable. When I am on the home page, I see the posts, but the links are not underlined and not clickable. What can I do to make that happen?

Example: the post 'Hello World' has a link at the word 'Wordpress' (to www.wordpress.com). Not visible on the home page but working after you click the post

http://gilhorn.com/wp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automatic post excerpts are trimmed to a specific character length, which means it's possible for HTML tags to be broken. You could end up with an open tag not being closed, for example.

To avoid this WordPress strips HTML tags from the content before trimming it for use as an excerpt. The are other reasons WordPress might want to do this. For example, it could be undesirable for an image to be included in what's supposed to be a short excerpt from the content.

If you want to use HTML in excerpts you need to manually write an excerpt into the "Excerpt" box on the post edit screen or, if your theme supports it, manually define a cut-off point in the content by using the Read More button in the editor. It looks like a dotted line splitting a box in two.

Some themes might not use excerpts at all and just show the full content, unless you have used the Read More button, in which case all the HTML will be preserved.

Ultimately the handling of excerpts comes down to the theme, since the theme decides which of the method/s of excerpting posts WordPress provides that it wants to use.

Comment: I thought links are stripped default from excerpts ?

Comment: Yes, along with other HTML, which is what I said. What did I say wrong?

Comment: I just changed to a different theme and now I see the links. Thanks

Comment: Sorry Jacob I probably read to fast and overlooked it...